# How to get the facebook tab id just created with graph API?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am using the graph API (Javascript) to create a tab programmatically on a facebook page. I have this sorted with the following code:

```
FB.api(pageId + '/tabs', 'POST', { app_id: APP_ID, access_token: access_token }, function(response) {
                if (!response || response.error) {
                    console.log('Facebook add app error ' + response.error);
                } else {
                    console.log('app has been added');
                    console.log(response);
                }
```

However I am trying to change the name of the tab and add a custom image to it. Is there a way to do it at the same time? Or do i need to loop through all the tabs of the page, check where my app has been installed, get the tab id and change the custom_name and custom_image? I looked inside the response but this is just a boolean when the installation is successful.
Thanks